# How do I compute absolute value of vector?

Tags: c++, vector

```
 std::vector<float> a {-0.2, 2.0, -0.9, 2.4, 22.0}
```

How to take absolute value of all vector elements?

The result should be

```
{0.2, 2.0, 0.9, 2.4, 22.0}
```

Comment: Loop over all elements, call `abs` on them?

Comment: Try using google : top of the list - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707945/how-to-find-the-absolute-value-of-a-vector

Comment: The requirements of this question are clear, and the scope is sufficiently narrow. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this code will help you, loop the vector and apply abs (function to find absolute value )

```
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] < 0)numbers[i] *= -1; //make positive.    _OR_   use numbers[i] = abs(numbers[i]);
        std::cout<<numbers[i]<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: or with for range of C++11: `for (auto& f : numbers) { f = f < 0 ? -f : f;}`

Comment: std::vector<float> absvalues(a.size());

    std::transform(
        a.begin(),
        a.end(),
        absvalues.begin(),
        [](double coeff)
        {
            return std::abs(coeff);
        }
    );

Answer (score 4):

[Use the formula `|a| = sqrt(sum(ai*ai))`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707945/how-to-find-the-absolute-value-of-a-vector):

```
float value = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) value += a[i] * a[i];
value = sqrt(value);
```

Comment: My math classes are some while ago now, but shoudn't it be |a| = sqrt(sum(abs(ai)*abs(aj))). Otherwise you may run into a exception when the sqrt of a negative value is taken. (Plus the result may be wrong)

Comment: It seems that it is not what OP wants. You compute a distance whereas OP wants to modify its vector to have positive float.

Comment: `ai*ai` = `abs(ai)*abs(ai)`, isn't it?

Comment: @Jarod42 Oops. The title confused me a bit. It said [*absolute value of vector*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Vector_spaces), which led to this answer.

Comment: The expression `a[i] * a[i++]` has undefined behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Did not know that! Thanks. But a for loop like `for(int i = 0; i < 42; a[i++] = 0);` should be valid, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfectly fine. The problem is when you access the same scalar value two or more times in different parts of the same expression, and one or more of those accesses is modification. (the actual rule is not quite that strict, but it's a good rule to follow imo, and it avoids this particular brand of UB).

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void v_abs( vector <int>  &x, double p[]) 
{ 
    int i=0; 


    while( p[i] < x.size () ) 
    { 
        if ( p[i] < 0 )
        { 
            p[i] *= -1 ; 
         } 
             i ++; 
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << v_abs << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will end up in an infinite loop if on the first value >= 0. Also not how you find the absolute value of a vector.

Comment: corrected. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Your print address of the function, you don't call it.

Comment: Your signature is strange... vector + c-array (and only size of vector is used for the vector...)

Comment: `system("pause")` is platform specific ...

Answer (score 1):

You create a function that receives as input the vector and returns another vector:

```
const std::vector< float >& absValues(std::vector< float >& vecIn)
{
   for(float &val : vecIn)
   {
      if (val < 0)
      {
          val *= -1;
      }
   }

   return vecIn;
}
```

---

And if you want the sqrt of the sum of all elements of the vector, then you should do it [as John Bupit said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915317/3062311) (IMHO is nice)